# Do any performance-enhancing drugs help increase tendon strength to prevent tendinopathies?

Tags: tendons

There exist some performance-enhancing drugs such as anabolic steroids that help increase muscle mass. Do any performance-enhancing drugs help increase tendon strength to prevent tendinopathies?

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5310744/ looked at the therapeutic use of hormones on tendinopathies but is rather inconclusive.

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.